# API Endpoints is missing properties with null value?

Tags: asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a couple of endpoints which returns jsons with properties missing, these properties being those which are null -  is this disabled by default and if so how do i enable this?

```
    services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = false)
        .AddJsonOptions(option => option.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter()));
```

Comment: I found a solution -  I am using a custom deserialize which was not handling null values, hence were they skipped.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure JsonSerializer

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddMvc()
             .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = false;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not specified, I'll assume you're using ASP.NET Core 3. The answer would be different if you were using ASP.NET Core 2.x.

**If you're using `NewtonfSoft.Json`**

You can configure the way JSON is serialized via the `AddNewtonsoftJson` extension method (in your `Startup.cs`):

```cs
var mvcBuilder = services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        var jsonSettings = options.SerializerSettings;
        jsonSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include;
    });
```

You're looking for the `NullValueHandling` property: using `NullValueHandling.Ignore` will skip the serialization of any property with a `null` value, while using `NullValueHandling.Include` will serialize `null` properties.

You can read the [full documentation of the `SerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) for more details.

**If you're using `System.Json`**

It's the same idea. You can configure the way JSON is serialized via the `AddJsonOptions` extension method (in your `Startup.cs`):

```cs
var mvcBuilder = services
    .AddMvc(options =>
    {
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        var jsonSettings = options.JsonSerializerOptions;
        jsonSettings.IgnoreNullValues = false;
    });
```

You can read the [full documentation of the `JsonSerializerOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=netcore-3.1) for more details.

Comment: Can you share your `Startup.cs`?